# Offline sync with Azure App Service

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-mobile-services, offline

I try to upgrade an objective-c project to Swift. I'm using `Azure App Service` with a `.NET` backend to store data from my mobile app (iOS) in the cloud. I just downloaded the quickstart for Swift project from the azure portal and followed the steps in the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-offline-data/) to enable offline sync functionality. However inserting an item in the table is not working. I am using the following code to store a new item in the backend

```
 var table : MSSyncTable?
 ...
 self.table!.insert(item) {
    (result) in
    let syncItem = result.0
    let error = result.1
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
    }
    ...
}
```

Stepping through the code at runtime revealed that `error` is `nil` so everything should be working fine, but I am not getting a new entry in my table storage.

Does anybody have experience with Azure App Service and Swift and can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the sync table, the actual operations to send and receive data from the server are explicit. These are represented by the `pushWithCompletion:error:` method on the sync context (for sending data up to the cloud), and the `pullWithQuery:query:queryId:completion:` method on your MSSyncTable.

Note that push automatically occurs when you pull as well.

I would expect the code to look something like:

```
var table : MSSyncTable?
 ...
 self.table!.insert(item) { result in
    let syncItem = result.0
    let error = result.1
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
    }
    table!.pushWithCompletion() { error in
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately MSSyncTable has no pushWithCompletion() function in Swift - as described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-offline-data/